# I cant watch YouTube videos on Firefox in Lubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, firefox, flash

If I try to watch video's or play games online, websites tell me that I don't have flash player installed.

When I try to install flash using the command line : `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` it tells :

```
the@the-desktop: ~$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package flashplugin-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'flashplugin-installer' has no installation candidate '
```

Which additional steps are needed here to install flashplayer?

Comment: What is your Lubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6   Version : 13.10   Codename : saucy

Comment: This version is not supported any more. That's why you can't install anything from repositories. Upgrade it to 14.04, and it will be solved.

Comment: @Pilot6   Thank You .    I taught that was the case but one more doubt  should i download  current lubuntu or Lubuntu LTS ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to a supported release likely will be the best solution - however if you go to https://www.youtube.com/html5 , you should be able to enable the HTML5 player:
[image]

This does not need flash installed, though you will need a recent enough version of Firefox, and probably the needed video codecs.

Comment: I agree; upgrade to 14.04. The HTML5 Player on YouTube is nice though because you can play videos at a faster or slower pace, for example 1.5x. If something requires Flash, I just open Chrome (I use Chromium though.) which has Adobe Flash baked in.